# Quantum algorithm for elliptic curve's private keys

Tags: elliptic-curves, post-quantum-cryptography

Is there a quantum algorithm to find private keys generated using elliptic curves ?

Comment: The problem as you ask it is difficult to answer, because you do not specify which private-public key generation algorithms you mean. But as far as I know, in general quantum computers can break discrete log, which most standard elliptic curve algorithms are based on. So, in general, the answer is that there is such a quantum algorithm.

Comment: @A.B. Is it not sufficiënt to say that the private-public key algirithm is bases on elliptic curves? Do you mean that I should specify which elliptic curve?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Shor's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shor%27s_algorithm), which runs only on quantum computers, solves *all* discrete-logarithm problem instances over all groups.

This obviously includes the elliptic curve discrete logarithm problem at the heart of [ECDH](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic-curve_Diffie%E2%80%93Hellman), [ECDSA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_Curve_Digital_Signature_Algorithm) and [ECIES](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrated_Encryption_Scheme). For a more detailed discussion of the details, see [this recent paper](https://eprint.iacr.org/2017/598).

However, there are things we can do with elliptic curves that are believed to which we don't know better quantum algorithms, like [elliptic curve supersingular isogeny-based key exchanges](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supersingular_isogeny_key_exchange).

Comment: The wiki only mentions Shor's algorithm for integer factorisation,  it should also mention all discrete logarithm problems then ?